# What is this trying to tell me?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, loops, termination

I am reading the book "How to solve it by computer" by RG Dromey. I am stuck on a sentence that is trying to explain termination of loops. Here goes the problem:

> Suppose we wish to establish that an array of `n` elements is in strictly ascending order (i.e. `a[1] < a[2] < ... < a[n]`) . To do this we can use the following instructions:
>
> ```
> a[n+1] := a[n];
> i := 1;
> while a[i] < a[i+1] do i := i+1
> ```

(Now if `n` is the number of elements, what does `i` stand for in this case? Does it stand for values?)

> If `n` was assigned the value 5 and the data set was 2, 3, 5, 11, 14, then the first assignment prior to the loop would result in the array configuration below:

(This is where I get confused.)

> ```
> a[1]  a[2]  a[3]  a[4]  a[5]  a[6]
> 2     3     5     11    14    14
> ```
>
> The two 14's guarantee that the test `a[i] < a[i+1]` will be false when `i = n` and so the loop will terminate correctly when `i = n` if not before.

(This is confusing.)

Comment: use code formatting to make your code look readable (and not with so much space between each line of code).

Comment: it's not really clear, not connected ... talking about loop termination then sorting arrays? assigning values ... i am a bit lost here, but as what `i` means, basic arrays , what i know in this case `i` is the index of the item in the array `a[i]` will be the `i-th` element (like 3rd, 4th ,5th element...)

Comment: I know. It is really weird but I wrote it exactly how the textbook has it. Would you like to me post a screenshot of it?

Comment: What page is this on? I notice read that the book was published in 1982 but sometimes still used a textbook. I think you're supposed to post questions like this on Programmer's Stack Exchange rather than Stack Overflow which for actual coding problems.

Comment: i am not sure if posting image will help, this site is more of code-oriented ...

Comment: If you're trying to ask what a specific statement in a book means, it would help if you could quote the statement *exactly* (and, preferably, prefix any quoted paragraphs with `>` to make them look different from your own writing; see the [Markdown editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for details). In a pinch, yes, even a screenshot would help. As written, I can't make *any* sense of your question.

Comment: Hey Dan, thanks for the heads up. I will post there in the future. It is on page 12 chapter 1.

Comment: i think this `a[n+1]= a[n]` should be `a[n+1]= a[n]+1` as `strictly ascending order` means values of each element is larger than the element before

Comment: What are you talking about? Loop termination or why there are two 14s. The reason why there are two 14s is clearly written. `a[n+1] = a[n]`.  stands for index. Is your question "how does the new array establish sort?"

Comment: There are two things that confuse me here. Im not nearly as smart as you guys are so I need help. It says "The two 14s guarantee that the test a[i]<a[i+1] will be false when i=n ". What does that mean?

Comment: Have you understood how arrays work? `a[i]` accesses the 'i-th' element of the array `a[.]`. To be honest it would make more sense to write `while (i<n and a[i]<a[i+1]) do i:=i+1` and not bother adding a spurious element to the end of the array (called a sentinel). If after this loop `i=n` then the array is in strictly ascending order.

Comment: Yes, I understand how basic arrays work. I just dont understand the wording of the book. For example when it says, "the first assignment prior to the loop would result in the array configuration below" What does it mean by the first assignment prior to the loop?

Comment: OK. I think it might be your English. They are a bit wordy. Here assignment means 'setting a value' in Pascal ':='. 'prior' means 'before' and configuration means 'values'. So he's saying setting the n+1 value before the loop means the array values will be (as shown).

Comment: Thanks for the [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1PhBX.png). Based on it, I've edited your question to quote to book more accurately, and to put the quoted material inside quote blocks. Feel free to edit it further.

Comment: Ok I think I understand. So when it is saying i=n it is referring to whenever a value equals another value, then terminate. In this case we have six elements. The fifth element equals the sixth element so the loop terminated at that point. Correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i is simply the index
i := 1;  means i is equal 1
i := i+1 means add 1 to i

n = 5

a[5] = 14
 a[5+1] = a[6] = 14

14 < 14 is false - the loop terminates

Comment: Bit harsh. The poster is on p.12 chapter 1 of a 1982 introduction to programming. Everything is hard.

Comment: Thanks for understanding Allen. Im not nearly as smart as you guys are and I can only hope to get as good as you guys. Im not asking for answers as I know that this is the easy way out and I wouldnt benefit from it. I am asking for clarification because I really want to learn this stuff.

Comment: @user249240 And that is not clarification?

Comment: No it is not. Not yet at least. Is n=5 an element or is it a value? In other words, does n=5 which in this case it would be in the third element or does n mean to look in the fifth element? Also, why are there two 14s?

Comment: i is index on the array.  a[5] is the fifth element.    You got a second 14 from this:  a[n+1] := a[n];

Comment: Ok. Now I think that I understand this. Thank you so much for the help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: You can give the answer a check if it is the answer